# Visual Studio não auto-completa nada

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

Sempre usei o visual studio e nunca tive problemas. Estou com a versão community 2017 instalada, e estava usando normalmente, porém, tive que dar uma pausa no desenvolvimento que vinha fazendo. Agora que voltei (uns 2 meses depois), saiu uma atualização e eu instalei sem problemas. O problema vem agora:

O visual studio não está mais sugerindo auto-completes de classes, nem mesmo imports/using. Ta funcionando igual um notepad++, só faz mudar a cor das coisas. Quando tento compilar, ele dispara um monte de erros "faltando import", "variável não declarada", tudo isso porque ele não está fazendo as sugestões de nada.

Queria a ajuda de vocês pra tentar solucionar este problema (já fiz a reparação dele no Visual Studio Installer, mas não resolveu).

Comment: Desinstale o Visual Studio, instale novamente já com a versão atualizada. E delete a pasta .vs que está oculta na raiz da sua solution.

Comment: Experimenta CTRL + J

Comment: Desinstalei e instalei de novo, funcionou. Valeu gente.